# Authentication is returning "401 (Unauthorized)" when it shouldn't

Tags: angularjs, node.js, authentication, sails.js, passport-local

I am setting up an authentication functionality for my first time and am getting some unexpected results after a user has been logged in. A colleague has given me an application with working authentication to model my application after and it seems like everything I have done is correct.

I am using AngularJS on the front-end, SailsJS back-end framework, and [PassportJS](http://passportjs.org/) authentication middleware.

My source is (for now) stored publicly... the backend API is on Github here ([API Github](https://github.com/djlovegrind/smallChange-API)) and the front-end code is found here ([Front-End Github](https://github.com/djlovegrind/smallChange-dashboard))

What basically happens is that the user

1. Hits the login button, which triggers this function

   ```
   login: function (credentials) {
       return baseAuth.customPOST(credentials, 'login').then(function (user) {
           $log.debug('User logged in: ', user);
           isAuthenticated = true;
           return user;
       });
   },
   ```
2. The controller logic for that customPOST is this

   ```
   login: function (req, res, next) {
      passport.authenticate('local', function (err, user, info) {
          if (err) { return res.json(err); }
          else if (user) {
              req.logIn(user, function (err) {
                  if (err) { return res.json(err); }
                  return res.json(user);
              });
          } else { return res.json(400, info); }

      })(req, res);

   },
   ```
3. In that step, passport should do its thing and login the user

   ```
   passport.use(new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'email', passwordField: 'password' },
   function(email, password, next) {
      User.findOne({ email: email })
          .exec(function (err, user) {
              if (err) { return next(err); }
              if (user) {
                   if (user.activated) {
                   bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function (err, valid) {
                       if (err) { next(err); }
                       if (valid) {
                           return next(null, user, { message: 'Logged In' });
                       } else { return next(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password'}); }
                   });
               } else { next(null, false, { message: 'User is not activated. Please contact admins.'}); }
           } else { next(null, false, { message: 'Could not find user with email ' + email }); }
       });
      }
    ));
   ```

In the console, I always get that this is successful.

Console reads:

```
User logged in:  Object {firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe", email: "john_doe@work.com", activated: true, isUser: true…}
```

4. Then, my understanding of what happens gets kind of fuzzy. I know the application then tries to see if the user is authenticated. IsAuthenticated gets triggered, which looks like this in AngularJS:

   ```
   isAuthenticated: function (force) {
       var deferred = $q.defer();

       if (isAuthenticated && currentUser) {
           deferred.resolve(currentUser);
       } else {
           return baseAuth.customGET('authenticated').then(function (user) {
               deferred.resolve(currentUser);
               isAuthenticated = true;
               currentUser = user;
               return user;
           });
       }

       return deferred.promise;
   }
   ```
5. It hits this action in the backend UserController

   ```
   isAuthenticated: function (req, res) {
      if (req.isAuthenticated() && req.user.isUser) { return res.json(req.user); }
      else { return res.send(401); }
   },
   ```

Then it fails :( `GET http://localhost:1337/user/authenticated 401 (Unauthorized)`  Neither req.isAuthenticated nor req.user.isUser pass. I have separated them out to individually test and neither of them are true. "isUser" is a value I default to true and is so it should be true for every single user in the db. req.isAuthenticated also fails, which I don't entirely understand.

Anyone have some insight into my problem? What I have I done wrong here?

Comment: I'm no sailjs developer but don't you need to configure sailjs session middleware? http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/Middleware?q=adding-or-overriding-http-middleware

Comment: Thats strange, b/c the working code I am following as an example doesn't seem to have that configured.... that probably is the source of my problem? I am checking now. thnx

Comment: Ok, I have actually gone and done that now. I get pretty much the exact same behavior though. Same issue.

Comment: Are these requests being made to a different origin than your front end?

Comment: There is also waterlock http://waterlock.ninja/

Comment: @idbehold yes, they are. Could that be the source of my problem?

Comment: @ZachCook LocalStrategy has a name `local` . Did you change it to `user` or is that a typo in  `passport.authenticate('user'...` ?

Comment: if `req.isAuthenticated()` is a promise, then should work with `.then`

Comment: @hassansin I had actually changed that a couple days ago after this post was first written. Changed to `'local'` now. Still get the same problem. I have now updated the post so the correct code is in the question! Thank you

Comment: Probably going to end up answering this one myself once I finally figure it out... not many answers forthcoming :-/

Comment: Did you give a try to my answer ?

Comment: @AlexisN-o you automatically got half the bounty b/c you got upvoted the most, but I haven't tried that yet. I blew up all the code and started fresh, and somehow on the second try it worked successfully.

Comment: I will investigate what exactly fixed the solution and post my answer here, if it turns out to be what you suggested in your answer that fixed it I will accept your answer for sure!

Comment: Sorry, I have been trying to recover the old version of my code to figure out what is was that fixed my issue, but I have ended up losing the old repo in the process. This could have been a great learning experience and been able to help others :/ My bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your frontend application has as a different origin than your backend application [the AJAX requests will not include the session cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Requests_with_credentials) and `req.isAuthenticated()` will never returns true.

Use the withCredentials options to force it.

```
$http({ withCredentials: true, ... })
```

It seems that Restangular uses the same options:

https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#setdefaulthttpfields

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage

Edit: You should also check [the server side configuration](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/anatomy/my-app/config/cors-js) as pointed out by idbehold

---

As suggested by Matan, you should really give a try to the sails-generate-auth generator on the server side.

https://github.com/sails101/even-more-passport

https://github.com/kasperisager/sails-generate-auth

Comment: He also needs to configure the `Access-Control` headers server-side to `Allow-Credentials` and make sure the `Allow-Origin` header is set to the actual request `Origin` header and not just `*`.

Answer (score 2):

Usualy a 401 'Unauthorized' error actually refers to a credentials error rather than 403 error which refers to a real Unauthorized error(forbidden) so you should check your client with Postman first to test It and then move on to the client.

although, I would highly recommend that you will drop down from that github project and use this tutorial to implmenet your passport.js authentication as you only need to execute 2 lines of code and some configurations rather then get messy with the code: https://www.bearfruit.org/2014/07/21/tutorial-easy-authentication-for-sails-js-apps/

Comment: That could be useful, what exactly do you mean by "credentials error" b/c the login was "successful" -- a.k.a their normal credentials of email and password were a match.  I think for some reason I am failing to set req.isAuthenticated to **true**

Comment: I faced this issue once and instructing passport to use sessions solved it for me. Add app.use(passport.session()) before you initialize your passport strategy and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

Since `passport.js` works using the underlying concept of strategies, you need to make sure that you authenticate using the right one. I don't see anywhere a strategy called 'user'

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'email', passwordField: 'password' },
function(email, password, next) {
   User.findOne({ email: email })
       .exec(function (err, user) {
           if (err) { return next(err); }
           if (user) {
                if (user.activated) {
                bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function (err, valid) {
                    if (err) { next(err); }
                    if (valid) {
                        return next(null, user, { message: 'Logged In' });
                    } else { return next(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password'}); }
                });
            } else { next(null, false, { message: 'User is not activated. Please contact admins.'}); }
        } else { next(null, false, { message: 'Could not find user with email ' + email }); }
    });
   }
 ));
```

should be changed to

```
passport.use('user', new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'email', passwordField: 'password' },
function(email, password, next) {
   User.findOne({ email: email })
       .exec(function (err, user) {
           if (err) { return next(err); }
           if (user) {
                if (user.activated) {
                bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function (err, valid) {
                    if (err) { next(err); }
                    if (valid) {
                        return next(null, user, { message: 'Logged In' });
                    } else { return next(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password'}); }
                });
            } else { next(null, false, { message: 'User is not activated. Please contact admins.'}); }
        } else { next(null, false, { message: 'Could not find user with email ' + email }); }
    });
   }
 ));
```

Also make sure your user's `isUser` flag is set to true.

Comment: I need to undo the up-arrow click but it won't let me. That actually doesn't help. Thanks anyways.