# Passport and SailsJS, how to get isAuthenticated() test to pass

Tags: sails.js, passport.js, passport-local

My code keeps failing here when the user tries to login:

```
isAuthenticated: function (req, res) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) { return res.json(req.user); }
    else { return res.send(401); }
},
```

It **FAILS** and I get `GET http://localhost:1337/user/authenticated 401 (Unauthorized)` in the console, even though the user has entered in a correct email and password.

Where in the code makes that test pass?

I have the related StackOverflow question with more info [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31082887/authentication-is-returning-401-unauthorized-when-it-shouldnt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that my frontend application has a different origin than  my backend application, so the AJAX requests will not include the session cookie and req.isAuthenticated() will never return true.

Use the withCredentials options to force it.

`$http({ withCredentials: true, ... })`